# I wrote a function to sort a string in alphabetical order but getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, io

`sort` and `swap` functions take pointer as argument, when I try it with 2 or 3 strings it works fine but for more than three its giving a segmentation fault, this is my code please let me know what's going on here and why it's giving this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get(int r, int c, char (*s)[c]);
void print(int r, int c, char (*s)[c]);
void sort(int r, int c, char (*s)[c]);
void swap(int c, char (*s)[c], char (*s1)[c]);
```

```
void main()
{
    int r;
    printf("\n\t enter no. : ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    char s[r][31];
    get(r,31,s);
    sort(r,31,s);
    printf("\n\tsorted list");
    print(r,31,s);
}
```

```
void get(int r, int c, char (*s)[c])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\t");
        scanf("%s", *(s+i));
    }
}
```

```
void print(int r, int c, char (*s)[c])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\t%s", *(s+i));
    }
}
```

```
void sort(int r, int c, char (*s)[c])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0, k = 1; j < r-1; j++, k++)
        {
            if(strcmp(*(s+j),*(s+k)) > 0)
            {
                swap(c, (s+j), (s+k));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
void swap(int c, char (*s)[c], char (*s1)[c])
{
    char (*t)[c];
    strcpy(*t, *s);
    strcpy(*s,*s1);
    strcpy(*s1,*t);
}
```

Comment: In the `swap` function you have the pointer `t` which you dereference, but it's never actually pointing anywhere valid. That means you will have *undefined behavior* when you dereference it. If you want to copy the strings (swap their contents) then `t` should not be a pointer. At least the location of this problem should have been easy to discover quicker than posting your question, if you just learned how to use a *debugger*. Being able to use a debugger yourself is a *crucial* thing for all programmers.

Comment: On another note, for any pointer or array `s` and index `j`, the expression `*(s + j)` is *exactly* equal to `s[j]`. The latter (`s[j]`) is much easier to read and understand. Not to mention it's actually less characters to write.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, as you adviised i wiil start learning and using debugger, thanks again for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is a pointer and as such it needs to be initialized, that is the reason for the segmentation fault, you need to allocate and assign the needed memory though a way better solution would be to simply make it an array:

```
void swap(int c, char (*s)[c], char (*s1)[c])
{
    char t[c];
    strcpy(t, *s);
    strcpy(*s,*s1);
    strcpy(*s1,t);
}
```

Or

```
char (*t)[c] = malloc(sizeof *t); // you'll need stdlib.h
```

With this second option you must free the memory:

```
free(t);
```

I would strongly advise the first solution though.

I would also strongly advise the use of a width limiter for the `scanf` in your `get` function, otherwise you are at risk of buffer overflow and consequently of undefined behavior.

```
scanf("%30s", *(s+i));
// discard extra characters in case the input is larger than the destination buffer
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
```

Note that `main` return type should be `int`.

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/6PjsEss71)